# Проблема с Robolectric

Tags: юнит-тесты, android, java, eclipse

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь тестировать андроид-приложение с помощью Robolectric, как советовали ранее, но, к сожалению, ничего не получается. Сразу скажу, что maven не использую. Скачал robolectric-2.4-jar-with-dependencies, добавил его к тестовому проекту, добавил нужные аннтоации к тестовому классу:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 11)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

и пытаюсь запустить тесты. Но тесты проваливаются с сообщением

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/net/Uri$Builder
```

После этого я добавил также библиотеку android.jar, но это не помогло. Ошибка сменилась на такую: `Stub!`

Насколько я понимаю, robolectric нужен для того, чтобы использовать android api в тестовых проектах без подключения к реальному устройству или эмулятору. Но это почему-то не работает - я все равно получаю ошибку `Stub!`, которая говорит, что реальные классы не подключены. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!